# Spark AR does not accept any scripting Functions, undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to develop a simple Instagram Filter and therefore trying to write a simple JS in Spark AR. 
Here is my code, basically copied from the tutorial https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/scripting/reactive:

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
export const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');
const TouchGestures = require('TouchGestures');

// Subscribe to tap gestures
TouchGestures.onTap().subscribe(function (gesture) {
    // Log a message to the console when a tap is detected
    Diagnostics.log('tap gesture detected');
});
```

Spark AR is giving me an instant error. The message is

```
Error:undefined is not a function
{
 "line": 6,
 "column": 0,
 "sourceURL": "script.js"
}
```

Am I missing any librarys or do I have to install anything in a addition than Spark AR?
I have absolutely no idea what is going wrong. :/ 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to the menu Edit -> Edit Properties -> Capabilities -> Touch Gestures and enable the option "Tap Gesture"

Answer (score 0):

Since old API has been deprecated you'll probably need the new code:

```
// How to load in modules
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Patches = require('Patches');
export const Diagnostics =  require('Diagnostics');


Promise.all([
    Scene.root.findFirst('number',{recursive:true})
]).then(function(results){
    const textHolder = results[0];
    Patches.outputs.getScalar('score').then(scoreValue =>{
        textHolder.text =scoreValue.toString()
    })
})
```